# Milnor: Morse Theory Theorem 3.1 why do we need $f^{-1}[a,b]$ to be compact?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, morse-theory

In Milnor's Morse Theory the Theorem 3.1 is given as follows:

> Let f be a smooth real valued function on a manifold $M$. Let $a < b$ and
> suppose that the set $f^{−1}[a,b]$, consisting of all $p \in M$ with $a \le f(p) \le
>  b$, is compact, and contains no critical points of $f$. Then $M^a$ is
> diffeomorphic to $M^b$. Furthermore, $M^a$ is a deformation retract of $M^b$,
> so that the inclusion map $M^a \to M^b$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Edit: The set $M^a$ is defined as $M^a:= f^{-1}(-\infty,a]$.

After the proof, he states that

> The condition that $f^{−1}[a,b]$ is compact cannot be omitted. For example
> Figure 3.2 indicates a situation in which this set is not compact. The
> manifold $M$ does not contain the point $p$. Clearly $M^a$ is not a
> deformation retract of $M^b$.

Figure 3.2 is the following:

[image]

But i dont understand why $f^{−1}[a,b]$ is supposedly not compact and how is it possible that $p \not\in M$ ? What am i missing? Why does $p \not\in M$ imply that  $f^{−1}[a,b]$ is not compact and why is it clear that $M^a$ is not a deformation retract of $M^b$?

Could someone elaborate?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: For a manifold (with or without boundary) $M$ of dimension $\ge 1$ and $p\in M$, $M\setminus \{p\}$ is always non-compact. Can you check that?

Comment: I think $p\not\in M$ is part of the definition of $M$.

Comment: In Milnor's example, $p \not\in M$ by definition. Omitting a point $p$ from a manifold still gives you a manifold and the resulting manifold cannot be compact (since any sequence that used to have $p$ as a limit, no longer has a limit). As for the bit about $M^a$ and $M^b$, you haven't given us the definitions Milnor is using for those sets.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments! The set $M^a$ is defined as $$M^{a} = f^{-1}(-\infty, a]$$

Comment: @Zest It's generally preferred to add details by editing the question rather than in the comments. As for showing that $M^a$ and $M^b$ are not deformation retracts in the example, are you familiar with fundamental groups?

Comment: Thanks Kajelad, i will edit my question. Yes, i am familiar with fundamental groups.

Comment: @Zest If $M^b$ deformation retracts to $M^b$, then we would have $\pi_1(M^a)\cong\pi_1(M^b)$, so it suffices to show the fundamental groups are not isomorphic.

Comment: Ahh, of course, now that's the reason $p$ is not sketched like "next to $M$" but rather in $M$. Just to make sure, this $p\not\in M$ is basically "the punctured manifold $M$? Is that what the figure is supposed to illustrate? Thanks for your help Kajelad.

Comment: @Zest Yes, it seems to me that Milnor is referring to the "punctured" manifold $M=S\setminus\{p\}$, where $S$ is the surface depicted in the figure.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kajelad, now it all makes total sense (together with all the other comments). It's greatly appreciated.